# Out of app settings for Android

Tags: android

To explain this. In the following screencap taken from my iphone there is some extra settings for the app Gitter. Like the Override URL. That is a field that Gitter will use in the app.

So my question is if there is a way to do the same on Android. I need something similar for my android app. But i could not find anything when i searched around the web (Google).

[image]

Comment: *But i could not find anything when i searched around the web* it is hard to believe, i found it with first hit ... yes, we call it [Preferences on android platform ...](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

Comment: Thanks a ton. Yeah i did not know what to search for really. The closest i got to finding what i want was something called sync settings. Which got me on the wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) on android.

And technical article could be found here [Settings](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

Comment: That's good .You can elaborate your answer for better approach .